# Generate audio driver hi current from MCU & DAC

Tags: microcontroller

I am very very new to microcontroller use. I am looking for a way to generate 2 different VLF frequencies that alternate for set time periods that will be pushed into an audio amplifier device to power coils (equivalent of solenoids I think). Also, if using a microcontroller, the device needs to be very small as overall space is an extreme premium. Should I look for a PWM or a uC with an onboard DAC?

Comment: PWM should be fine if you can filter out the PWM switching frequency to any degree to which it is objectionable.  Using unfiltered PWM feeding a switching power stage rather than a linear audio amplifier would be common for that application, if you can get the switching frequency high enough that the mechanical system cannot respond to it.  The switching amplifier will be much more efficient and thus smaller and cooler; very carefully built ones are even used for audio now.